# python beautifulsoup next page

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

here is my current code to scrape specific player data from a site:

```
import requests
import urllib.request
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
from pandas import ExcelWriter
import lxml
import xlsxwriter

page = requests.get('https://www.futbin.com/players?page=1')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'lxml')
pool = soup.find(id='repTb')

pnames = pool.find_all(class_='player_name_players_table')
pprice = pool.find_all(class_='ps4_color font-weight-bold')
prating = pool.select('span[class*="form rating ut20"]')


all_player_names = [name.getText() for name in pnames]
all_prices = [price.getText() for price in pprice]
all_pratings = [rating.getText() for rating in prating]

fut_data = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'Player': all_player_names,
        'Rating': all_pratings,
        'Price': all_prices,
     })

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('file.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')

fut_data.to_excel(writer,'Futbin')
writer.save()

print(fut_data)
```

This is working fine for the first page. But I need to go through 609 pages in total and get the data from all pages.

Could you please help me to re-write this code to make that working? I am still new and learning with this project.

Comment: put the code in a loop 1 to 600. regenarete the url with loop index. and dont forget to change file name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate over all `609` pages, parse each page and at the end save collected data to `file.xlsx`:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

all_player_names = []
all_pratings = []
all_prices = []

for i in range(1, 610):
    page = requests.get('https://www.futbin.com/players?page={}'.format(i))
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'lxml')
    pool = soup.find(id='repTb')

    pnames = pool.find_all(class_='player_name_players_table')
    pprice = pool.find_all(class_='ps4_color font-weight-bold')
    prating = pool.select('span[class*="form rating ut20"]')

    all_player_names.extend([name.getText() for name in pnames])
    all_prices.extend([price.getText() for price in pprice])
    all_pratings.extend([rating.getText() for rating in prating])

fut_data = pd.DataFrame({'Player': all_player_names,
                         'Rating': all_pratings,
                         'Price': all_prices})

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('file.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
fut_data.to_excel(writer, 'Futbin')
writer.save()
```

Comment: thanks for your detailed help! Howeserv I get an error now: line 14, in <module>
    pnames = pool.find_all(class_='player_name_players_table')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all'

Comment: oh..it seems I got blocked from the URL thats why I got that error: Oops, there was an error - 403. Your client does not have permission to access this page at this time. Please try again at in a few minutes.

Comment: did I have to put a sleep timer somewhere? Was I accessing too fast?

Comment: I'm not sure about that. But you can try